# what does CV symbol mean?

Tags: windows, winapi, dll, symbols, pdb-files

I have a dll which has said to have CV symbols. I checked CV means Code view, but would like to know more about this symbole format. How it compares to PDB format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeView IS the format of PDB files.

Comment: You can see whether your binary (exe, dll...) is bound to a PDB file using PeStudio (www.winitor.com)

Comment: you can easily see whether your DLL contains Symbols (PDB) information using PeStudio.